# PHP split each paragraph into array

Tags: php, html, regex, split

I want to *split each paragraph* into an array.

My current approach doesn't work:

```
$paragraphs = preg_split( '|</p>|', $text, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```

---

How can I get from this:

```
$text = <<<TEXT
        <p>Hello!</p>
        <p style="border: 1px solid black;">How are you,<br /> today?</p>
TEXT;
```

to this

```
$paragraphs = array(
     '<p>Hello!</p>',
     '<p style="border: 1px solid black;">How are you,<br /> today?</p>'
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use DOMDocument() for this like as follows

```
 <?php
$text = <<<TEXT
    <p>Hello!</p>
    <p style="border: 1px solid black;">How are you,<br /> today?</p>
TEXT;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$paragraphs = array();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $node)
{

    $paragraphs[] = $dom->saveHTML($node);

}
print_r($paragraphs);
?>
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
  [0] => <p>Hello!</p>
  [1] => <p style="border: 1px solid black;">How are you,<br> today?</p>
)
```

Comment: Fantastic solution.

Answer (score 4):

You've forgotten the attribut limit and the flag is PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE

```
$text = <<<TEXT
        <p>Hello!</p>
        <p style="border: 1px solid black;">How are you,<br /> today?</p>
TEXT;
$paragraphs = preg_split( '|(?<=</p>)\s+(?=<p)|', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
//                                                here __^^


print_r($paragraphs);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] =>         <p>Hello!</p>
    [1] => <p style="border: 1px solid black;">How are you,<br /> today?</p>
)
```

Comment: what in case of nested paragraphs (if any) ?

Comment: @Letmesee: It certainly doesn't work fine, but why do you want nested paragraphs?

Answer (score 2):

Their could be many ways..
You follow below steps as well.

```
$array = explode("</p>", $text);
```

This will break your text at every `</p>` into an array row
Then apply following for loop to add `</p>`

```
foreach($array as $row)
{ 
  $paragraphs[] = $row."</p>";
}
```

print_r($paragraphs);

Comment: @pbaldauf Have you try my answer,Here it is forking fine for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure every closing tag will be exactly

you can use explode:

```
  $paragraphs = explode('</p>', $text);
```

Else, if there may be any space you have to use a regex:

```
  $paragraphs = preg_split('/<\/\s*p\s*>/', $text);
```

Comment: Does it give cases where to closing tag isn't `</p>`?